# Best way to simulate a right foreign key join on two KTables

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

Writing a Kafka Streams application and trying to figure out the best way to do what is essentially a right foreign key join. The data comes from a CDC-driven compacted topic and the structure is fairly simple - let's say there's a `Rule` that can apply to zero or more people.

```
class Rule {
  String id;
  //some other important rule stuff
}
```

```
class RuleAppliesTo {
  String id;
  String ruleId;
  String personId;
}
```

So a `Rule` may or may not have any `RuleAppliesTo` children. I want to process the Rule in either case.

I end up consuming two topics and turning them into KTables, and I want to join the two KTables into one, so that I can do further processing.

So far, the solution I've come up with is grouping `RuleAppliesTo` records by `ruleId` and then aggregating them into a list. I can then do a regular left join, since the two KTables are then copartitioned.

```
KTable<String, RuleAppliesTo> applicants = build.table("applicant_topic")
    .groupBy((key, applicant) -> new KeyValue<>(applicant.getRuleId(), applicant))
    .aggregate(
        () -> ArrayList::new,
        //adder
        (key, applicant, list) -> {
            list.add(applicant);
            return list;
        },
        //subtractor
        (key, applicant, list) -> {
            list.remove(applicant);
            return list;
        }
    );
```

However, this has problems with deletes and updates. A tombstone record will simply shorten my list, it won't delete the old record from the downstream join result. I think I can get around that by adding an `isDeleted` field and setting that in the subtractor, and then in the join `ValueJoiner` returning a null if the field is `true`.

Updates are an even bigger problem, I think. They generate both an add and a subtract call, and theoretically if the `ruleId` field is updated then the add and subtract could end up in different partitions and be processed in any order. So I can't mark records as `deleted` in the subtract and then tombstone them, since I may end up deleting instead of updating if the add happens first.

Is there a better way of doing this? The data structure I have is quite common, I think, so I'd expect this to be an issue people have run into, and solved, before.

Comment: Kafka streams already offers a DSL for doing foreign key joins: https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html#join(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable,java.util.function.Function,org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner)

Comment: @AyoubOmari Only for left joins, I need to do a right one.